# Append data to different sheets in an excel in R

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, openxls

I have a dataframe like

**All_DATA**

```
ID  Name  Age
1   xyz   10
2   pqr   20
5   abc   15
6   pqr   19
8   xyz   10
9   pqr   12
10  abc   20
54  abc   41
```

Right now I have code which works for subsetting the data based on `Name` and the putting them into different excel ,but Now I want it in same excel in different sheets.

Here is the code for putting them into different excel

```
library("xlsx")
library("openxlsx")
All_DATA = read.xlsx("D:/test.xlsx")

data.list=list()
for(i in unique(All_DATA$Name)){
data.list[[i]] = subset(All_DATA,NAME==i)
write.xlsx( data.list[[i]],file=paste0("D:/Admin/",i,".xlsx"),row.names=F)
 }
```

Is there any way by which a single excel file with data on multiple sheets can be generated.

Thanks

Domnick

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
write.xlsx(data.list[[i]], file="file.xlsx", sheetName=paste0("Sheet_",i,".xlsx"), row.names = F)
```